# Как сделать так чтоб при вызове клавиатуры экран поднимался над ней?

Tags: java, android, chat

Есть экран чата, и когда нажимаешь на поле для написание сообщения открывается клавиатура и скрывает часть экрана с последними сообщениями, как это пофиксить? Сделать так чтоб при открытии клавиатуры экран с сообщениями поднимался над ней?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы, в манифесте нужно указать данную строку в активности которая должна изменяться:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Должно быть так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <application ...>
        <activity
            android:name=".TestInputActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test_input"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Так же есть подобный вопрос, где есть и другие решения данной проблемы: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411056/how-to-adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998156/how-to-move-all-elements-in-constraint-layout-up-on-focus-in-edit-text-field). [Неплохой туториал](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/move-layout-when-keyboard-shown/) по вашей проблеме.